# Configuring a HTTP and HTTPS web accelerator using Varnish

Tags: cache, https, varnish

I have installed and configured varnish on my new server. The server is currently working for http traffic.

I would like to also forward SSL traffic to my webserver. It is not necessary to cache this traffic at this time.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If I understand your question correctly, you want to handle the SSL layer at your webserver behind Varnish, right? Why would want a caching server to only forward traffic? You can use plain firewall (`iptables`) rules or have your webserver connected directly at port 443 for this without the need for traffic to pass Varnish.

Comment: Those are great suggestions. I have decided to just forward HTTPS traffic from the firewall to the webserver bypassing the Varnish cache.

Comment: Your information about the iptables was very helpful since I was not sure if I would be able to get the requested changes in place at the firewall. If I was not able to change the firewall from forwarding all traffic to the cache, I would have tried to use the iptables to pass the HTTPS traffic along to the webserver. (I think we both agree that is a bit silly, but if I were unable to make the firewall change)

Note: Our firewall, cache, and web server are all separate devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading [the comment by gertvdijk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249138/configuring-a-http-and-https-web-accelerator-using-varnish#comment310213_249138), I have decided that the best strategy is to forward HTTPS traffic from the firewall directly to the web server, bypassing the Varanish proxy (as I don't need it to cache this traffic).

> If I understand your question correctly, you want to handle the SSL
>   layer at your webserver behind Varnish, right? Why would want a caching server to only
>   forward traffic? You can use plain firewall (`iptables`) rules or have your webserver
>   connected directly at port 443 for this without the need for traffic to pass Varnish.

Comment: If you mark this as the answer, it will be removed from the "Unanswered questions" queue.

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure if I should mark my own summary of another users comment as the answer.

Comment: yeah, I checked on meta as unanswered questions were getting me down.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think varnish support caching for https, if you want caching with ssl, nginx might be a better choice for you